# Reduce line spacing in beamer caption

Tags: beamer, captions, line-spacing

How do I reduce the line spacing in captions in beamer? I tried `singlespacing` but that wouldn't work.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usecaptiontemplate{
\footnotesize%\singlespacing
\structure{\insertcaptionname~\insertcaptionnumber:}\insertcaption}

\begin{document}
\frame{{Test} 
\begin{figure}
\caption{A very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long caption.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{test.png}
\end{figure}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply place a `\par` following the caption to use the baselineskip of the `\footnotesize`. If you need a more precise control, you can define the fontsize and the baselineskip seperatly using `\setbeamerfont{caption}{size*={10pt}{6pt}}`

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

%\setbeamerfont{caption}{size*={10}{6}}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{%
    \structure{\insertcaptionname~\insertcaptionnumber:}
    \insertcaption\par
}

\begin{document}
\frame{{Test} 
\begin{figure}
\caption{A very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long caption.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow! thanks a lot. this must be the shortest answer to any question I have ever seen, just add \par;-)

Comment: @PatrickT Works fine for me. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @samcarter, thanks for your comment. On a second look, I realize I was too hasty and hadn't read everything properly. I didn't have the ``\par`` at the end of the caption and without it the linespacing doesn't work. You do explain this very clearly. Sorry for wasting your time! Thanks again.